# what happened while `int &i` is a property of class

Tags: c++

What happened when `int &i` is a property of a class? What the constructor did? The stack and the memory?  I write a demo to explain the problem. I run it on my computer, and get the result of a certain run ：

```
45  2000572096
```

the demo is:

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
    A(int a, int b):i1(a),i2(b){};

public:
    int i1;
    int &i2;
};

int main()
{
    A a(45,60);
    std::cout << a.i1 << " " << a.i2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did it do? That's undefined.

Comment: try to define `int param_i2 = 60` and pass this value...

Comment: Turn on your warnings (`-Weverything` in clang), if your compiler is smart enough, you'll get a message saying that you are binding a temporary to `i2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class member variables that are references can only be constructed, not assigned.
This code constructs the variable `int &i2` from the constructor parameter `int b`.

Parameters are a lot like local variables, they aren't there any more after the call.

So, i2 is now referring to an integer that not longer exists. That's undefined.

This is why you are getting the strange output.

Btw, in case your curious, references are often implemented as pointers and with the hidden use of the address of operator. Thus pointer that the reference has inside will now likely be pointing to where the parameter int b was on the stack, but as I said above, it isn't there any more, so undefined behaviour results if the reference is accessed.
You could search on the web for "returning a reference to a local variable" to learn more.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for fixing the grammar/spelling.

Answer (score 1):

That is undefined behaviour, because `i2` is referencing a local variable (`b`) that is destroyed once the constructor has finished.